# Inject data by dynamic token

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have 2 components:

```
class ComponentView {
  @Input() key!: string;
  @Input() data!: string;
}
class ComponentSettings {
  @Input() key!: string;
}
```

They are instanciated in different places using dynamic component creation technique.

`ComponentView` has data object which I want to share to `ComponentSettings` via DI. Important to use `key` prop to make sure that connected instances by the `key` uses proper shared value.

How I see this solution, but it wan't work:

```
class ComponentView {
  @Input() key!: string;
  @Input() data!: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    Injector.create({ providers: [{ provide: this.key, useValue: this.data }]})
  }
}
class ComponentSettings {
  @Input() key!: string;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const data = this.injector.get(this.key);
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not think this is going to work. Injector.create is just returning the new injector instance, so still need to share this instance. But for your issue you should just provide a service on top of both components and share the value through a service property wich is way easier and less complex.

Comment: Does it has to be DI? This case could easily be solved by using `Service` which take advantages of RxJS Subject